# Modulo operation on floating point numbers on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, modulo

I wish to perform a modulo operation between two floating point integers in PostgreSQL. Specifically, I wish to enforce angle-arithmetic, e.g. forcing angles to lie in the interval [0,2*pi] after some mathematical operations.

I can see `fmod` or such is not officially supported in SQL. Is there any reasonable workaround?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using [0, 2π] rather than [−π, π]. The latter has some nicer properties for floating-point.

Comment: What are these?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Perhaps the π character did not display correctly for you? The question is why you use [0, 2*pi] rather than [-π, π]?

Comment: Exactly. The questions is what are the nicer properties of using [−π, π] and not [0, 2π].

Comment: Primarily reduction to a symmetric interval can be performed with no error. For illustration, consider a two-digit decimal format. If we map −.012 to [0, 2], the closest representable value is 1.9. (The exact result is 1.88, which is not representable since it has three digits, so it is rounded.) With a symmetric interval, no value is increased in magnitude; none is mapped from a finer region of the floating-point format (lower exponents, smaller steps between representable values) to a coarser region (larger exponents, larger steps). With [0, 2π], your small negative angles are lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is trivial to create such a function yourself:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fmod (
   dividend double precision,
   divisor double precision
) RETURNS double precision
    LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT dividend - floor(dividend / divisor) * divisor';
```

You can use that to solve your problem:

```
SELECT fmod(1000, 2.0 * pi());

       fmod        
-------------------
 0.973536158445768
(1 row)
```

This function can be inlined, so it should be pretty efficient.

Comment: Rounding errors can cause a result of this code to be outside the target interval.

Comment: Generally, floating-point arithmetic is an approximation of real arithmetic. But that also means it must be used carefully. When the goal is to reduce a value to an interval modulo a period, it ought to produce a result in the interval. A solution should avoid or correct for rounding errors as necessary to achieve that. A proper symmetric remainder operation is exact and has no rounding errors, as the exact mathematical results are exactly representable. An asymmetric remainder operation will need to have rounding errors, but it does not need to return results outside the interval.

Comment: (A symmetric remainder operation returns x-yn, where n is the integer nearest x/y. So it always returns a value with magnitude less than or equal to x, so the precision required for an exact answer is always available. For this asymmetric remainder, where n is floor(x/y), some results will have magnitude greater than x, and in a higher binade, so less absolute precision is available.)